# Looping in terraform with multi-level Maps

Tags: azure, loops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform question.  I want to create a vnet with multiple subnets by reading in all the variable information in from a yaml file into locals.  For instance:

```
vnets:
  vnet1:
    name: "core-euw"
    location: "westeurope"
    address_space: ["10.0.0.0/22"]
    subnets:
      - name: "adds"
        address_prefixes: "10.0.0.64/27"
      - name: "mgmt"
        address_prefixes: "10.0.0.96/27"
  vnet2:
    name: "core-ussc"
    location: "westeurope"
    address_space: ["10.1.0.0/22"]
    subnets:
      - name: "adds"
        address_prefixes: "10.1.0.64/27"
      - name: "mgmt"
        address_prefixes: "10.1.0.96/27"
```

In my .tf file, I want to create only one resource block for azurerm_virtual_network and loop on the number of vnets (vnet1, vnet2) in the yaml file.  The code I have works great for creating the two vnets, but I can't seem to figure out how to parse the subnets: section under each vnet for creating the multiple subnets within it.  My .tf file is below:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

locals {
  settings = yamldecode(file("./settings.yaml"))
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-network" {
  name     = "rg-global-core-network"
  location = "South Central US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnets" {
  for_each = local.settings.vnets

  name                = "vnet-${each.value["name"]}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-network.name
  location            = each.value["location"]
  address_space       = each.value["address_space"]

  dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = local.settings.vnets.subnets
    content {
      name           = each.value["name"]
      address_prefix = each.value["address_prefixes"]
    }
  }
}

output "name" {
  value = [for subnet in local.settings.vnets]
}
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 1):

In your dynamic `subnet` block you should not use `each`. Instead it should be `subnet`:

```
  dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = each.subnets
    content {
      name           = subnet.value["name"]
      address_prefix = subnet.value["address_prefixes"]
    }
  }
```